# Is there any way to get what field wasn't equal using EqualBuilder

Tags: java, apache-commons

Is there any way to get what field and the corresponding value that caused the inequality when using EqualBuilder

```
@Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
    Meeting meeting = (Meeting) o;
    EqualsBuilder equalsBuilder = new EqualsBuilder();
            return equalsBuilder.append(basicMeetingInformation, meeting.basicMeetingInformation).append(subject, meeting.subject)
                    .append(emailParticipants, meeting.emailParticipants).append(ownerEmail, meeting.ownerEmail).append(timeZone, meeting.timeZone)
                    .append(start, meeting.start).append(end, meeting.end).append(notes, meeting.notes).append(recurrence, meeting.recurrence)
                    .append(recurrenceEnd, meeting.recurrenceEnd).append(recurrentInstanceId, meeting.recurrentInstanceId)
                    .append(scheduledMeetingRooms, meeting.scheduledMeetingRooms).isEquals();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, You could have easily a custom extension (with 1 additional (String) parameter, like: `myAppend(T lhs, T rhs, String name)`). But basing on `EqualsBuilder` ([it is quite intelligent](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/EqualsBuilder.html), and stops comparing, once inequality is detected), you can get only the **first** field and value, which violates equation, like:

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.EqualsBuilder;

public class MyEqualsBuilder extends EqualsBuilder {

    private final Map<String, Object> violatedFieldValues = new TreeMap<>();

    /**
    * @param name - the name of appended property.
    * @see #append
    **/
    public <T> EqualsBuilder myAppend(T lhs, T rhs, String name) {
        assert (null != name);
        append(lhs, rhs);
        if (violatedFieldValues.isEmpty() && !isEquals()) {
            violatedFieldValues.put(name, rhs);
        }
        return this;
    }

    /** 
    * Gets the Map of field name to (right hand) value,
    * which first violated the equality of this equals builder.
    * Contains 0 - 1 entries.
    **/  
    public Map<String, Object> getViolatedFieldValues() {
        return violatedFieldValues;
    }

}
```